# sqlexception was unhandled in c#

Tags: c#

I dont know why but when i want to insert image and save , it will be error by SQLException was unhandled (?)

```
namespace Project
{
    class Connection
    {
        private SqlConnection con;
        private string connectString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"; 

        private DataTable dTable;
        private SqlDataAdapter adapt; 
        private SqlDataReader read; 
        private SqlCommand cmd;

        public Connection()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(connectString);
        }

        public DataTable executeQuery(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in database: "+e);
            }

            con.Open();

            dTable = new DataTable();
            adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectString);
            adapt.Fill(dTable);

            return dTable;
        }

        public void executeUpdate(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in database: " + e);
            }

            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            read = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // this is the error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual code executing your query is outside of the try/catch clause.

Comment: @aevitas so what should i do with this ExecuteReader ? kinda confused with this error

Comment: what query are you executing?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  con.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MsProduct VALUES ('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + stock + "','"+ prodPrice +"', '" + image + "')");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` when inserting or updating record, for selecting data `cmd.ExecuteReader()` is used.

so change this line:

```
read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

to this:

```
int NoOfRowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

See details at [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx)

Also you can see this [**tutorial**](http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html)